# Quaternion - Conjugate

Tags: matrices, quaternions

I'm trying to get the conjugate of a Quaternion but I'm not sure if I'm using the formula correctly.

I have a Quaternion of:  $q = 2 - i + j + 3k$

and with help online, the conjugate of a Quaternion is defined by:

$a^* = a_1 - a_2 i - a_3 j - a_4 k$

But if I apply this to the Quaternion I have it looks as if it is just subtracting each `ijk` from each other, or maybe I'm just not understanding this correctly.

I'd like to better understand what is going on here and how to get the conjugate of a Quaternion properly. I'm happy to follow any web links that better explain the method of doing this.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The conjugate of $2-i + j + 3k$ is $2+i - j - 3k$. You negate each of the nonreal coefficients. This is analogous to the conjugate of a complex number.

Comment: Hi @EthanBolker, are you just performing an inverse to the plus and minus operations?

Comment: @nonbee Maybe you wanna do some basic math, like complex variables, before stepping up to quaternions?

Comment: Yes. That's a somewhat nonstandard way to say it, but you can call it that if it helps you. My wording is standard.

Comment: @ClassicEndingMusic thanks but no thanks

Comment: Appreciate the feedback @EthanBolker!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quaternion $q$ can be written in one and only one way as
$$
q=a_0+a_1i+a_2j+a_3k
$$
with *real* $a_0$, $a_1$, $a_2$ and $a_3$. By definition, the conjugate of $q$ is
$$
q^*=a_0+(-a_1)i+(-a_2)j+(-a_3)k
$$
(but usually written as $q^*=a_0-a_1i-a_2j-a_3k$). In your case
$$
a_0=2,\quad a_1=-1,\quad a_2=1,\quad a_3=3
$$
so
$$
-a_1=1,\quad -a_2=-1,\quad -a_3=-3
$$
and therefore
$$
q^*=2+1i+(-1)j+(-3)k
$$
usually written, for short, $q^*=2+i-j-3k$.

Comment: I just wasn't understand what was being negated and why, this clears things up!

Comment: I know this is a different question but can I just ask,when normalising a quaternion, let's say the quaternion used in my question, do I square root that by 2² − i² + j² + 3k²?

Comment: More generally (because this works with functions of quaternions as well): replace $i$ with $-i$, $j$ with $-j$, and $k$ with $-k$. To normalize a quaternion $q$, perform $q/\sqrt{q\overline{q}}$, where $\overline{q}$ is the conjugate.

Comment: @nonbee The norm of $q$ is $\sqrt{qq^*}=\sqrt{a_0^2+a_1^2+a_2^2+a_3^2}$, in your case $\sqrt{4+1+1+9}=\sqrt{15}$ and the normalization is $\frac{2}{\sqrt{15}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{15}}i+\frac{1}{\sqrt{15}}j+\frac{3}{\sqrt{15}}k$.